# java Generic<T> same as Generic?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

According to the theory of type erase in java, I think the following two code piece should compile to same java class so have same bytecode.

```
public class Generic {
    private Object t;

    public void hi() {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

> javac Generic.java
>
> mv Generic.class Generic1.class

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T t;

    public void hi() {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

> javac Generic.java
>
> mv Generic.class Generic2.class

compare Generic1.class with Generic2.class, they are totally difference.

So what's wrong with my think? And how Generic compiles to bytecode?

---

**[EDIT]**

javap -v nice tip, thanks.

But I can't get a detail understanding with bytecode in short time.

**I'd like to know if Generic compiles with T erase to Object.**

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not seeing that extra cast you mention - `diff`ing the outputs gives only constants (thats what the things starting with hashes are, right?). Nice tip for `javap -v` though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in the classes here do have the same *bytecode*, but bytecode is not the only thing that goes in the class file.

The class file also contains the declarations of the class and its members, including the class's superclasses and implementing interfaces, the parameter and return types of its methods, the types of its fields, etc. All of those declarations keep generics (so that classes compiled separately against this class later can be checked). So the class files are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Type erasure** (not type erase) doesn't mean your two examples will have the same bytecode, it means basically that if you can do type casts manually for non-generic legacy types or the compiler will do it for you for parameterized types (no runtime overhead).

Comment: Actually, it *does* mean the class will have the same bytecode. However, code that uses the class may not have the same bytecode if the type `T` is returned to them; but it will in this case, since the type `T` never shows up in the public interface.